# How to have a parameter ignore weekends in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a capacity dashboard in Tableau that is designed for the user to select a start date and the days required for a new project to add onto a stacked bar chart. Currently, I am getting the wrong calculations due to this piece of my IF formula

> AND [Date] <= [Start Date] + ([Days Required])

as it is including weekends in that part. I don't have weekends in my data source, my views, and date is discrete. Is there a function, or way to get that particular part of the IF formula to ignore weekends?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Can you include the entire calculation and some sample data.  You might be looking for what @shmicah put below... or you could be looking to skip weekends and just count business days.  It isn't totally clear.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something I came up with..

Q.Add days to start date by and skip the weekends (in other words, consider only weekdays).

Solution:
Determine the end_date by adding the days to start_date
[End Date]:

```
DATEADD('day',[Days],[Start Date])
```

I've created 2 calculated fields for this.
1. Add_days - To add days to [days] field when a week comes between [Start Date] and [End Date]. 
[Add_days]

```
[Days]+DATEDIFF('week',[Start Date],[End Date])+DATEDIFF('week',[Start Date],[End Date])
```

2. End_date_final - To get the final end date that excludes weekends and gives a new End Date.
   [End_date_final]

```
IF DATENAME('weekday',DATEADD('day',[Add_days],[Start Date]))='Saturday'
THEN
DATEADD('day',[Add_days]+2,[Start Date])
ELSEIF DATENAME('weekday',DATEADD('day',[Add_days],[Start Date]))='Sunday'
THEN
DATEADD('day',[Add_days]+1,[Start Date])
ELSE
DATEADD('day',[Add_days],[Start Date])
END
```

Now you can use the condition in your IF condition as

```
AND [Date] <= [End_date_final]
```

Let me know if more help is needed.
Have a nice day :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! I combined yours with shmicah's and it made it a little shorter and simpler. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

`datename('weekday',TODAY())` can give you the string name of the day - keyword being 'weekday' versus just 'day'. You can check:

```
if datename('weekday',TODAY())='Saturday' OR datename('weekday',TODAY())='Sunday'
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Combining yours with Koushik's allowed a simpler formula that ignored the weekends. Appreciate the help!